# Is anyone using Racket commercially?

Tags: lisp, scheme, startup, racket

I've been reading about how Racket is used for academic research, but I'm having a problem finding commercial success stories in business and/or start ups. Is anyone having any success using Racket commercially or am I barking up the wrong tree? I ask because I've got an idea for a start up and am evaluating languages and tools at the moment.

Comment: There are a number of them, you should look at the mailing list archives where the subject comes up from time to time.  (Here's a [random quick link](http://www.gameenginebook.com/gdc09-statescripting-uncharted2.pdf) for a (large) pdf file from Naughty Dog which was mentioned on [ycombinator](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2201964) (which is also using racket, btw).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several companies are using Racket commercially.  One significant example is [Untyped](http://untyped.com), which built their scheduling/workflow tracker system [Kahu](http://www.getkahu.com/) in Racket, and also uses it for other projects.

Answer (score 3):

We are using mzscheme commercially. Mzscheme is power R5RS implementation from plt (racket).